# Error in checking file downloaded properly through curl

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to run curl command to download a file using sftp and after that checking if that file downloaded or not, but somehow my code is printing "File downloaded successfully" everytime even when the file did not download.

Here is my script:

```
#!bin/bash
curl -k -u "user:user" -ssl -o file.zip sftp:domain
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download file"
    exit -1
fi
echo "File downloaded successfully"
```

Comment: Does the remote file not exist, or is there a problem downloading an existing file?

Comment: Add '-v' to curl to get details on a failed download. Exit status is 0 for a 404 http request so it does not reflect some protocol errors but only the exit code of curl itself.

Comment: When the file is not there and my code tries to download it, it should be printing the file download was not successfull, but the code does not do that

Answer (score 1):

Try using `--write-out` option as

```
#!bin/bash
rcode=$(curl --silent --write-out '%{response_code}' -k -u "user:user" -ssl -o file.zip sftp:domain)
if [[ "$rcode" -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download file"
    exit -1
fi
echo "File downloaded successfully"
```

For a 404 http response

`rcode=$curl --silent --write-out '%{response_code})' http://localhost:8080/tyu
echo "$rcode"
404`

[sftp response codes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes), success is 0.